# In clause doesn't work

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ZINVN 
WHERE ZINVN.GRID IN
(
        SELECT SMGRID 
        FROM SKU FULL JOIN OTBCLS ON SKU.SKCLCD = OTBCLS.SMCLCD
        WHERE SKSKU=800234
);
```

This query doesn't return a result, while if I run it without the in clause it returns the expected result.

Also the query inside `()` works well and returns the expected result.

Where is the problem in my query?

Comment: do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Are you sure there are rows in `ZINVN` where `GRID` is equal to one of the values returned by the subquery?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan .. a stack trace? There's no error, and this is SQL - you don't get a stack trace..

Comment: How many results does the subquery return?

Comment: use ALAIS for subquery fields

Comment: Try WHERE GRID IN instead of WHERE ZINVN.GRID IN.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Sorry maybe I trying to say: Error cause. Oracle sql for example shows the error at line and column sometimes.

Comment: are you sure that ZINVN.GRID and SMGRID are of the same data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should alias your query to indicate where the columns come from.
Also, an INNER JOIN will be faster than a FULL OUTER JOIN which doesn't quite make sense for two reasons
1. Having the `WHERE SKU=` clause reduces the FULL JOIN to a LEFT JOIN since rows must match from the left table
2. Keeping records in the LEFT table serves no purpose since `SMGRID` will be NULL for the purpose of the `IN()` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM ZINVN 
WHERE ZINVN.GRID IN
(
        SELECT OTBCLS.SMGRID 
        FROM SKU JOIN OTBCLS ON SKU.SKCLCD = OTBCLS.SMCLCD
        WHERE SKU.SKSKU=800234
);
```

This existential test normally executes faster when written in the equivalent form below using a correlated EXISTS test.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ZINVN 
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM SKU JOIN OTBCLS ON SKU.SKCLCD = OTBCLS.SMCLCD
      WHERE SKU.SKSKU=800234 AND ZINVN.GRID=OTBCLS.SMGRID
      );
```

Having said that, have you checked for extra spaces being the difference between 'ZINVN.GRID' and 'OTBCLS.SMGRID'?

Comment: Thanks richard, the problem was that Grid = 'L1' while OTBCLS.SMGRID was = L1 .. without single quotation.